# what was my backend before i changed it to 'agg'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i ran a code with this line

```
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

i read about it and what i understood is that matplotlib will show my graphs in different gui.
then i tried to plot some graphs in a different code and got this error:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure. plt.show()
```

i read in a question here that i need to change the backend to 'TkAgg' using tkinter. and it worked but now it shows the graphs in a different window than im used to. how can i change it back to what it was?

p.s im very new to programming and sorry for my english.

Comment: Could have been TkAgg or qt5agg and the such

Comment: [What is a backend?](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

Comment: @EB97 Cool, glad I could help. For future reference, it's possible to change the backend via code, by setting the relevant environment variable, as so: os.environ['MPLBACKEND'] = 'TkAgg' or whatever backend one prefers for the task at hand.